# If col is empty string, make adjacent column empty as well

Tags: python, pandas

Consider this sample df:

```
colAnum    colB   colCnum    colD
123        House  456        Book
           Car    789        Table
891        Chair             Porch
```

I am trying to roll through this df and if the "num" column is an empty string, then make the adjacent column, to the right, empty as well.

This is the expected output:

```
colAnum    colB   colCnum    colD
123        House  456        Book
                  789        Table
891        Chair
```

I attempted this with variations on this:

```
for idx, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    if df.iloc[idx, col] == '':
       df[idx+1,col] == ''
```

I am sure I am missing something simple to make this occur, but cannot work my way around it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `shift` with `mask`

```
out = df.mask(df.eq('').shift(axis=1).fillna(False),'')
  colAnum   colB colCnum   colD
0   123.0  House   456.0   Book
1                  789.0  Table
2   891.0  Chair
```

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Thanks.  Had not used shift before so this was a new one that I will remembrer.